# Nested json, making it visual

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a verry complex JSON string from the database that looks like this:

```
    {
    "id":"2016666",
    "dt":"2012",
    "object_extends":[
        {
             "extend1":{
                "id":"2016666",
                "dt":"2012",
                "active":"true",
                "object_extend":[
                    {
                        "extend2":
                        {
                           "id":"2016666",
                            "secondary":null
                        },
                        "extend3":
                        {
                            "id":"2016666",
                            "pet":"willy"
                        }

                    }
                ]
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

Now i want to visualize this in a tree, but with the d3.js library it needs a name for each object(which i think is weird). So are there any ways to visualize this as a tree? Or do i need to modify the stored procedure(which returns this string) so that i can fit d3?

Comment: nobody knows a way? i'm really stuck...

Comment: have you looked at this? [Collapsible Tree Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033) ?

Comment: Do you have control of the JSON that is generated in the API. This JSON is a strange way to organize tree data. Could you make extend2 and extend3 attributes of the hashes instead of keys?